# Getting values from THIS scope after init function (persistency inside CFC)

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I'm initiating a CFC like this.

```
<cfscript>
  lock scope="application" timeout="5" {
    application.mycfc = new mycfc();
  }
  writeOutput(application.mycfc.readVars());
</cfscript>
```

In the CFC, I'm setting some properties.

```
component output="false" accessors="true" {
  property name="title";
  property name="foo";

  this.title = "mycfc";

  function init() {
    this.foo = "bar";

    // I can now properly read this.title, or this.foo.
    return this;
  }

  function readVars() {
    // Here, I can read this.title, from the constructor space, but I can't 
    // read this.foo. It's just blank (because the default value of the 
    // `default` attribute of `property` is "")
  }
}
```

Because of the implementation (caching in Application), I can instead use `application.mycfc.foo` in `readVars()`.

Because of `this` name, it's hard to Google for details. I thought it would be persistent throughout the CFC's life, but apparently it is not?

I surely could do something like

```
var self = application[this.title]; // or application.mycfc
```

Or perhaps even

```
this = application[this.title];
```

In functions where I want to get/set without typing `application.mycfc` each time.

Just trying to make sure I'm not doing something wrong, or reinventing the wheel.

In my real implementation, I'm pulling from rows from a database to populate a struct.

Comment: I think, you can try to use request scope or client scope to get/set the value without typing application.mycfc each time.

Comment: What is the component used for, storing application level settings? How frequently does it write values?  As mentioned below, writes to any shared scope must be locked to avoid race conditions. So just wondering if the component *should* be stored in the app scope ...

Answer (score 5):

Scopes in ColdFusion components (.cfc):

- `this`
  is the public scope, read/write from anywhere
- `properties`
  is a magical scope, read/write only via accessors (a.k.a. getters/setters) from anywhere
- `variables`
  is the private scope, read/write only within your component

All of these scopes can coexist, but `this.x` is NOT the same field as `property name="x"`!

Since you are using a component with `accessors="true"`, all your `property` fields can only be read via getter and written via setter. So if you want to write your `title` property, use `setTitle("mycfc");` instead of `this.title = "mycfc";`. Same goes for the `foo` property. Use `setFoo("bar");` instead of `this.foo = "bar";`. If you want to read the properties, use `application.mycfc.getTitle()` and `application.mycfc.getFoo()`. If you want to set properties at runtime, use `application.mycfc.setTitle("something")`. Note that writing to a shared scope such as `application` should happen in a `cflock` to avoid race conditions (thread-safety).

If you don't need accessors at all, you can simply use public fields instead (`accessors` is missing here, i.e. set to false):

```
component output="false" {
    this.title = "mycfc";
    this.foo = "";

    function init() {
        this.foo = "bar";

        return this;
    }

    function readVars() {
        return this;
    }
}

application.mycfc = new mycfc();
writeOutput(application.mycfc.title); // mycfc
writeOutput(application.mycfc.foo); // bar

application.mycfc.title = "something";
writeOutput(application.mycfc.title); // something
writeOutput(application.mycfc.foo); // bar
```

Public fields are usually not recommended though as they break encapsulation.

Comment: Yeah, public fields can also be modified by other code outside the component. That's usually undesirable (and could create race conditions, since the cfc is stored in the app scope)  so ... don't use public fields unless you fully understand the implications.